# How to debug ASP inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm working on a client's Classic ASP site and some images that are supposed to display in a footer aren't showing up. I'm also not seeing any error message. There is some javascript that should be reading in a list of image file names from a SQL Server database. Those images are displayed from a local folder based on the list of names from the DB. This is taking place in javascript, but it looks like there's some ASP inside the function. I honestly have no idea how that is supposed to work or how to debug it (i.e., ASP in a javascript function). Other parts of the site rely on the ADO connection, so I'm pretty sure that's being created correctly. How do I debug this? I'm using Chrome, which seems to have some good tools for debugging. Here's the function I'd like to be able to step through and investigate more. I'm just not sure how. Also, when I view this chunk of javascript in Chrome, only part of it is there! Here's the function:

```
function declareLogos() {
    <%   ' get logos

    SQL = "SELECT l.LogoFileName, p.SortOrder FROM InrixCustomerLogo l join InrixCustomerLogoPage p on l.LogoCode = p.LogoCode WHERE p.PageFileName = '" & fn & "' AND SortOrder > 0 ORDER BY SortOrder"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oLOGO = oConn.Execute(SQL)
    logoerror = Err.Number
    On Error Goto 0
    x = 1  ' array counter

    %>

    <% If NOT logoerror Then %>
    <% Do While NOT oLOGO.EOF %>
    i[<% =x %>] = '<% =oLOGO("LogoFileName") %>';
    <% oLOGO.MoveNext : x = x + 1 : Loop %>
    <% End If %>

    imax = <% =x-1 %>;
    ilast = <% =(((x-1)*4)/4) %>;  // <% =(((x-1)*4)/4) %>   this is imax - 1 that is divisible by four
}
```

On the actual web page, here's what Chrome's tools show for this function:

```
function declareLogos() {


     imax = 0;
     ilast = 0;  // 0   this is imax - 1 that is divisible by four
}
```

Any guidance in debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is _server-side_ code that writes text to the client. It has nothing to do with Chrome, which can only see the HTTP response.

Comment: What you have here is ASP assigning values to JavaScript variables as it is rendering the page. The ASP is not "inside" the JavaScript.

Comment: Ah. I see. It looks like I need to set up my project differently in VS than I have it now, then I'll be able to set breakpoints, etc. That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: So you either have a `logoerror`, or the query return nothing (`oLOGO.EOF` is true).

Answer (score 0):

Please not that the ASP code is not inside your javascript code. It is inline ASP codes used for simple usage. It is not recommended to use inline codes if possible. You could write the code in the code-behind instead.

This is how you can break at a specific point in inline code

```
<%  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
   // Code will be present here
%>
```

In your case

```
<%   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
' get logos

    SQL = "SELECT l.LogoFileName, p.SortOrder FROM InrixCustomerLogo l join InrixCustomerLogoPage p on l.LogoCode = p.LogoCode WHERE p.PageFileName = '" & fn & "' AND SortOrder > 0 ORDER BY SortOrder"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oLOGO = oConn.Execute(SQL)
    logoerror = Err.Number
    On Error Goto 0
    x = 1  ' array counter

    %>
```

**Update:**

In classic ASP `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` is not available(unless you write a ComVisible wrapper around it). Thanks to @Frédéric Hamidi for pointing it out.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` is not available in classic ASP (unless you write a ComVisible wrapper around it).